# POST command=addHost&response=json 530 Unable to add the host

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I'm configuring cloudstack, I added datacenter vcenter and the cluster but to add the host I can't do it

syetems: venter 6.7 host ESXI 6.003

Comment: help please it so important

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.